# Not connecting with onBillingSetupFinished method

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing, google-play-console

I'm trying to show Toast inside onBillingSetupFinished method but it's never connect with it.

**Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(activityMainBinding.getRoot());

    BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
    billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "B", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> list) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "C", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I uploaded apk to Google Play Store and they accepted it but code still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine. It's just that you are unable to get the toast.
There are two things you can do:

Replace the Toast with

```
Log.d("GoogleBillingService", "onBillingSetupFinished: billingResult: Yes/Your Result");
```

And check the LogCat at GoogleBillingService to get the results.

The toast is probably running on a different thread and hence you don't see it when you run the application.

Try using

```
((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        { 
             Toast.makeText(context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: It's working , But how you know there is different thread, Can you give me documentation who says that?

Comment: I think experience is what told me this. Because the BillingClient starts the connection as an asynchronous process. All such processes are run on different threads and not the main thread so as to not block the UI.